# Distribution of the number of heads showing

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics

If Y is the number of heads showing when X fair coins are tossed, X is the number of spots showing when a fair die is rolled.

What is the distribution of Y?

I know that X could be 1,2,3,4,5,6, with each probability equal to 1/6.

Thanks,
Jack Liang

Comment: Consider tabulating the possibilities: there aren't very many (only 2+3+4+5+6+7=27) and that will help you *see* what the answer must be.

Comment: Is there a way to find the distribution of Y?

Comment: whuber just gave you a way to find the distribution of Y - direct enumeration of the probability of each possible outcome (and some addition). What else do you seek? If you want an algebraic approach, see the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability): $\Pr(A)=\sum _{i}\Pr(A\mid B_{i})\Pr(B_{i})$